# Update Magento ver. 2.2.4 to Magento ver. 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, extensions, algolia

If we update Magento ver. 2.2.4 (php 7.1) to Magento ver. 2.3 (php 7.3,8.0) we again need to buy plugins? Or plugin are system dependent.
extensions (plugins) are

1. ALGOLIA SEARCH.
2. WEBKUL
3. MAGEPLAZA
   and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each of your third party modules (*extensions*) for compatibility with the version of Magento you want to upgrade to.

Contact the module developer to see if there is a compatible version and upgrade the modules as required.

Whether you will have to pay for the upgrade will depend on the vendor.

Magento 2.3 will be end of support in September 2022, so perhaps you should be concentrating on moving to 2.4.